# Does loss of life count as being dealt damage?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Some cards require players to have taken damage for a bonus effect to take place. Does loss of life count as being dealt damage?

[image: Fathom Fleet Cutthroat] [image]

These are the two cards in specific that I am talking about.

Comment: Even if the answer was yes, Fathom Fleet Cutthroat destroys a creature that was dealt damage, and Skymarch Bloodletter makes a player lose life.

Comment: @murgatroid99 oh, i misread. i thought it was destroy a creature owned by a player who was dealt damage.